# New line Email not getting using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

**Firstly,** I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve them but no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**Problem:** Can not get "Lucy 3" email on Array.

I want to all Email stores category-wise (To / CC / BC /BCC ). I am getting an Email header and using a regular expression filter email. it's working fine. but in case **To** or **From** any email add a new line so the new line email is not getting on my Array.

Demo link [**Here**](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/zah)

**Code**

```
$String_Header = 'From support@test.co.uk  Wed Nov 20 15:48:00 2013
Return-Path: <support@test.co.uk>
X-Original-To: mailbox@my.domain.com
Delivered-To: mailbox@my.domain.com
Delivered-To: techinfo@test.co.uk
from: "Lucy 1" <support@lucky1.co.uk>,"Lucy 2" <support@lucky2.co.uk>,
"Lucy 3" <support@lucky3.co.uk>
to: TestTo <techinfo@test.co.uk>';

function ProcessTicketPostHeaders($headers)
{
    if (is_string($headers)) {
        $_headersWeWantToKeep = array("from", "to", "cc", "bcc");
         $headers = preg_replace('/\r?\n /', ' ', $headers);        
        $_pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $_headersWeWantToKeep) . '):.*$/im';       
        if (preg_match_all($_pattern, $headers, $headers)) {                
            $headers = implode("\n", $headers[0]);
        }
    }
 
    return $headers;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(ProcessTicketPostHeaders($String_Header));
```

**OutPut:**

```
from: "Lucy 1" ,"Lucy 2" ,
to: TestTo
```

**I want Output:**

```
from: "Lucy 1" ,"Lucy 2"  ,"Lucy 3"
to: TestTo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match all lines that do not start with any of the values in `$_headersWeWantToKeep` or an empty line if you don't want to match all that followed after the last match.

The full pattern could look like

```
^(from|to|cc|bcc):.*(?:\R(?!(?:(?1)|$)).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUFqMv/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/bFa33)

For example

```
$String_Header = 'From support@test.co.uk  Wed Nov 20 15:48:00 2013
Return-Path: <support@test.co.uk>
X-Original-To: mailbox@my.domain.com
Delivered-To: mailbox@my.domain.com
Delivered-To: techinfo@test.co.uk
from: "Lucy 1" <support@lucky1.co.uk>,"Lucy 2" <support@lucky2.co.uk>,
"Lucy 3" <support@lucky3.co.uk>
to: TestTo <techinfo@test.co.uk>';

function ProcessTicketPostHeaders($headers)
{
    if (is_string($headers)) {
        $_headersWeWantToKeep = array("from", "to", "cc", "bcc");
        $headers = preg_replace('/\r?\n /', ' ', $headers);
        $_pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $_headersWeWantToKeep) . '):.*(?:\R(?!(?:(?1)|$)).*)*/m';
        if (preg_match_all($_pattern, $headers, $headers)) {
            $headers = implode("\n", $headers[0]);
        }
    }

    return $headers;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(ProcessTicketPostHeaders($String_Header));
```

Output

```
<pre>from: "Lucy 1" <support@lucky1.co.uk>,"Lucy 2" <support@lucky2.co.uk>,
"Lucy 3" <support@lucky3.co.uk>
to: TestTo <techinfo@test.co.uk>
```

Comment: thanks for anwser . i trying your code but last record is not correct ... please show link  https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/zaq

Comment: Extra words are added on last array . https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/zaq

Comment: @Sumitpatel that is the value of capture group 1. The full match is in index 0. If you don't want the group 1 value, you can use `^(?:from|to|cc|bcc):.*(?:\R(?!(?:(?:from|to|cc|bcc)|$)).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/eBInr7/1

Comment: (plus) +1 for future helping. I understand your answer and I trying to more optimize for my requirement